# Why exactly is there a difference between performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

To begin, yes this is for homework, and I've been trying to read and understand.  Nothing has just said why one is better or worse.  Anyway, in SQL Server using the Adventureworks data base, the following 3 queries are run:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012; 
GO 
--1 
SELECT LastName
FROM Person.Person 
WHERE LastName = 'Smith'; 
--2 
SELECT LastName 
FROM Person.Person 
WHERE LastName LIKE 'Sm%'; 
--3 
SELECT LastName 
FROM Person.Person 
WHERE LastName LIKE '%mith';
```

LastName is a NonClustered index.  Why do queries 1 and 2 perform identically and query 3 perform much worse that the first 2?

Comment: Small tip if you're using SQL Management Studio. Click on the Execution Plan button and it will tell you how SQL got from your query to the results. Zerkms's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the phone book that is sorted by last names

1. Lookup for all "Smith"s
2. Lookup for all people whose last name starts with "Sm"
3. Lookup for all people whose last name ends with "mith"

Do you see now?

Comment: So it is just common sense?  The first two tell you exactly where start looking, and the last one makes you check each entry?

Comment: @NewProgrammerJames A great deal of performance issues are common sense ;-)

Comment: @NewProgrammerJames: not common sense. Indexes are implemented similarly to what you see in a book: it's a sorted structure.

Comment: That is the best and most concise explanation of this issue I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

Keys in an index are sorted so that finding a value is easier. For string-type values they are sorted alphabetically (ascending or descending). That makes it easy to locate any value based on the whole value or its begininng.

The problem with matching on anything at the start (`'%mith'`) is that SQL Server cannot use the sorting of the index in any way (cannot do a lookup). It has to actually go through the whole index (doing a scan).

Answer (score 0):

Think about the index in the back of a book or a phone book. Everything is alphabetically ordered. So if you search for "Smith" or a name that starts with "sm", then it is easy to flip to the "s" section and find the name. If you search for every name that ends in "mith" then you have to search through every page in the phone book because there might be someone whose name starts with any letter but ends with "mith" like someone with the last name "blacksmith".